# Django Queryset filter in view

Tags: django, html-table

```
{% for event in events.all %}
  <tr>
    <th>{{events.filter(date__exact = event.date)|length}}{% ifchanged event.date %}{{event.date}}{% endifchanged %}</th>
```

I am trying to fill out the same events with the same date. Then I can use it as rowspan for my table which would make it looks nice.
But django doesn't allow doing filter in the view. How should I do it?

Comment: Are you actually saying: "But Django doesn't allow doing filter in the TEMPLATE"?

Answer (score 2):

Django does allow to filter in views. Once you import your model into views, then you can filter based on the fields in the model. See below for a sample:

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class My_Model(models.Model):
    event_date = models.CharField()
```

views.py

```
from app.models import My_Model

def view_function():
    query = My_Model.objects.filter(event_date='enter what you are looking for')
```